# Can I see individual achievement progress for Half Life 2 Episode 2?

Tags: steam, achievements, half-life-2, half-life-2-episode-two

I've started working on the [Get Some Grub](http://www.trueachievements.com/a11100/get-some-grub-achievement.htm) achievement, it requires me to kill 333 antlion grubs throughout the first 2 chapters. From reading some guides I gather I should be able to track my progress towards the goal, checking that I didn't miss anything. But I can't see any progress for this achievement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in the **in game** menu :

Escape > Achievements ( Or something ) and you have a progressbar with the number. Good luck on this one. Got 332 on my first try without looking at a guide

Comment: Ah! Totally turned a blind eye on that menu item. Thanks! P. S. Note: it only works while the game is loaded.